# Cakephp using multiple layouts for same page

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a project in cakephp. I am using the View/Layouts/default.ctp file to store my header and footer, that would apply to all my pages in the application. 
however, there is another layout that i want only certain pages to use, along with the header and footer.

How can i make a page use both the layouts?

Comment: Why do you want both layouts in same page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one layout can be used for each page load. However, you could place your header and footer code into [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) that then are usable in both of your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend views. Put the header/footer in View/Common/default.ctp and extend it.

```
$this->extend("/Common/default");
```

You could also use elements or blocks, depending on how your layout is set up and what you need.
[Read more](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views)

Answer (score 0):

You can change layouts from controller or view depending upon your logic.

```
// from a controller
public function admin_view() {
    // stuff
    $this->layout = 'admin';
}

// from a view file
$this->layout = 'loggedin';
```

For reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use multiple layout..........

class IndexController extends AppController {

    public function test1() {
        $this->layout = 'layout1';
    }

    public function test2() {
        $this->layout = 'layout2';
    }

    public function testn() {
        $this->layout = 'layoutn';
    }

}
```